# Confusion with homogenous ODE: why $[\ln (y)]'=y'/y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question which is quite basic, however, I am unfortunately having trouble understanding the explanation.

I am utilizing a textbook which states the following:$$\frac{dy}{dt}+a(t)y=0.$$It then states that "divide both sides of the equation by y and rewrite it in the form"$$\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{y}=-a(t).$$.However, it then states:$$\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{y}=\frac{d}{dt}\ln |y(t)|.$$I am confused as to how this could be the case, as$$\frac{d}{dt}\ln |y(t)|=\frac{1}{y(t)},$$not$$\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{y}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{1}{y}.$$I would truly appreciate any and all help regarding this.

Comment: It is simply the chain rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

Are you aware of the chain rule?

Whenever the involved expressions make sense, you can proceed as follows:

\begin{align*}
[f(g(x))]' = f'(g(x))g'(x)
\end{align*}

At the given case $f(x) = \ln(x)$ and $g(x) = y(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct when you differentiate with respect to $y$:
$$\dfrac {d\ln y}{dy}=\dfrac 1  y$$
But you have this where $y(t)$ is a function of the variable $t$:
$$\dfrac {d \ln y}{dt}=\dfrac {d \ln y }{dy}\dfrac {dy}{dt}=\dfrac 1{y}\dfrac {dy}{dt}=\dfrac {y'}  y$$